# Android ActionBar Tab Navigation

Tags: android

I am following http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gMu8XhxUBl8 example. Setting up the tabs is working fine. On each tab, I am using a cursor to get the data from SQLite and display it. where should I write that code ? In TabActivity ? In AFragmentTab ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your AFragmentTab
Im sure this is where your work if any will take place.

Comment: If so, I need to pass a variable to AFragmentTab, How do I do that ?

Comment: YOu can pass it as a intent. Is it a String,Boolean or what?